# addEventListener for specific animationName

Tags: css-animations, addeventlistener

I have written the code below. I'm trying to invoke functions one after the other based on 'animationend' eventlisteners. The problem arises in the js code after `startScreenContainer.classList.add('thisFadeOut');`
I expected the function: `removeStartScreen();` to be called by the animationend event of: thisFadeOutAnim. I'm guessing that `removeStartScreen();` is being called by the animationend event of rainbowFlashAnim, because the element startScreenContainer is being assigned the classes thisFadeOut & thisRemove at the same time. So thisFadeOutAnim doesn't get chance to run. I have searched online and have found some info on animationName but I can't get my head around how to implement the concept. Or am I just doing everything all wrong!?

**My question:** Is there a way to add an event listener to events of a specific animation?

```js
    var startButton = document.querySelector('#startButton');
    startButton.addEventListener('mouseup', startButtonClicked);
    
    
        function startButtonClicked(){

        startButton.classList.remove('startButtonPulse');
        startButton.classList.add('startButtonClicked');
        startButton.innerHTML = "LET'S GO!";
        startButton.addEventListener('animationend', fadeOutStartScreen);

        function fadeOutStartScreen(){
            var startScreenContainer = document.querySelector('#startScreenContainer');
            startScreenContainer.classList.add('thisFadeOut');
            startScreenContainer.addEventListener('animationend', removeStartScreen);

            function removeStartScreen(){
                   startScreenContainer.classList.add('thisRemove'); 
                }
            }
        }
```

```css
.startButtonPulse{
    animation: buttonPulseAnim 1.5s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
    
}

@keyframes buttonPulseAnim {
    0%      {transform: scale(1);}
    12.5%   {transform: scale(1.05);}
    25%     {transform: scale(1);}
    37.5%   {transform: scale(1.05);}
    50%     {transform: scale(1);}
}

.startButtonClicked{
    animation: rainbowFlashAnim 0.5s;
    animation-iteration-count: 4;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes rainbowFlashAnim{
    20%      {background: cyan;}
    40%      {background: lime;}
    60%      {background: magenta;}
    80%      {background: red;}
}

.thisFadeOut {
    animation-name: thisfadeOutAnim;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes thisfadeOutAnim {
    from    {opacity: 1;}
    to      {opacity: 0;}
}

.thisRemove {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I have worked out a way:

```
element.addEventListener('animationend', function(e){
    if(e.animationName === 'nameOfYourAnimation'{
        //do something...
    }
});
```

Beautiful!!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it but I don't you can attach an event to some animation.

I think you shall do it like this

btn1 clicked fire function1 
  function1:
     start animation1 for 2s
     after 2s call function2 (user setTimeout)

function2:
     start animation2 for 1s
     after 1s call some other function

Comment: Maybe you are correct. It's dissapointing because if it could be done, I would only have to tweak the css parameters to change the timings/durations of events that occur in the DOM.